# How to export a vuex module of a library inside a nuxt app

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vuex, vuex-modules

I have a component called scheduler which has its own vuex store.
To wrap it, I defined a file called bundle.js wherein I have set the following code. I will be using this file as a target for building.

```
import Scheduler from './App.vue';
import store from './storeBuild';

export default {
    install(Vue, options) {
        if (!options || !options.store) {
            throw new Error('Please initialise plugin with a Vuex store.')
        }

        options.store.registerModule('schedulerLib', store)

        Vue.component('scheduler', Scheduler)
    }
}
```

Here is the package.json file where I have the build script as

```
{
  "name": "scheduler",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "main": "dist/scheduler.common.js",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "build-bundle": "vue-cli-service build --target lib --inline-vue --name scheduler ./src/bundle.js" // The script to build the bundle
  },
"dependencies": {
  ..........
 }
}
```

and my store file will directly export the object instead of creating a store

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default {
    namespace: true,
    state: {
     layout: 'main-layout',
     nestedObject: {},
    },
    mutations: {
     // Has more than 20 handlers
    },
    actions: {

    },
    modules: {
    }
}
```

After running the build-bundle I had the code along with my dist folder push into the git. Then I add it as a package in my other app using the gitlab link (ie) yarn add git+https://abc:sdbfkn45234ADFGDF@gitlab.com/abc/task-scheduler.git#master // here task-scheduler is the repo name.

I add this package in another vue app and it works completely fine but in nuxt Iam not able to do the same since the store implementation is already preset etc. How Iam I supposed to do this.

**New Update as per HamidReza's comment**

For the nuxt-app I did the following

1. In the store folder, I have a folder called projectPortal inside which I defined a file called scheduler.js which has the following content.

```
import Vuex from 'vuex'

const store = new Vuex.Store({
 state () {
   return { counter: 0 }
 },
 mutations: {
   increment (state) {
     state.counter++
   }
 }
})

export default store
```

I am exporting the store instance since I need it for my plugin thats mentioned in point No 2.

2. Defined a file called libraries.js inside plugin folder with the below content

```
  import Vue from 'vue'
  import store from '../store' // this is were the problem is...the store is just an object and not a store instance becoz in nuxt the store instance is not created by the user but its done automatically during runtime.
  import scheduler from 'scheduler';
  Vue.use(scheduler, { store });
```

3. Then in the nuxt.config.js

```
    ...
    plugins: [
     {
       src: '~/plugins/libraries',
       ssr: false
     }
    ]
    ...
```

But this isn't working. Please help.

Another question related to this [How to access a external library vuex module inside nuxt app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66227043/how-to-access-a-external-library-vuex-module-inside-nuxt-app)

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can use nuxt plugin to do that

Comment: I have updated the code block that I tried in nuxt...please check the question